# Is there a way to create dynamic union type with possible values returned from typeof

Tags: typescript

I thought since I can use as a regular function `typeof(variable)` I should be able to define a type

```js
type TypeOf = ReturType<typeof typeof>
```

but tsc is complaining

```
Cannot find name 'typeof'.(2304)
Exported type alias 'TypeOf' has or is using private name 'typeof'.(4081)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDKBPADgUxAMwBQDkAhhACYECUAUFWljACoaYDyOSMASplAK4BOYJlgA8dbO3G4AfEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` is not a function, but rather a built-in operator in JavaScript. If you want to have a union of all possible return types of `typeof`, just use this pre-defined one:

```
type TypeOfReturn = 
 | "undefined" 
 | "object" 
 | "boolean" 
 | "number" 
 | "string" 
 | "symbol" 
 | "function" 
 | "object"
```

You could also use a wrapper function to infer the type.

```
function _typeof(arg: any) {
  return typeof(arg)
}

type TypeOfReturn = ReturnType<typeof _typeof>
```